the installation of the subpanel outside gaps in the wood Advice?
The location of the subpanel will be on the exterior wall it is wood that has little gaps I have two thoughts 1 to use wing nuts into the exterior wall and mount flush. 2 to install unistrut and mount the panel on that. I am leaning towards the unistrut  the picture is where the panel will be mounted. Could I get some thoughts?

There should not be an issue mounting directly to the wall. If you will feel better about it, caulk  the sides and top of the box.

If I go flush with the wall there is the little stand out to keep a gap between the panel and the mounting of it.  I am wondering if I go that route the holes that I am making to push the wings in rubber gaskets of some kind to seal those or rubber washers. There will be the movement of tightening the bolts into it if I caulk those holes as I am trying to do that wouldn't the caulking fall out or push in?  Any advice you have would be great. I did read somewhere that they are designed to have a gap in the back would sealing it up veto that?

Why are you trying to flushmount a standard NEMA 3R loadcenter enclosure? They really aren't designed for this, and in an outdoor situation, you probably don't want to do something that'd compromise the panel's ability to shed water or cause it to drain water into the wall cavity where it may not be able to exit so well...

I should have worded it semi-flush, I did not do a very good job of explaining it.  Can you install it semi-flush and then caulk up the sides?  wouldn't the caulk basically enclose that gap that is required to be between the enclosure and the wall making that against code?

@BBrown -- you need a special flashing  flange (either as a bolt-on kit or built-into the box) for N3R semiflush installs.  Can you explain why a normal surface mounted panel install is not practical in your situation?
